# Bug with carousel with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I trying make a carousel using bootstrap 4, but I have a problem with arrows and cycles. Using bootstrap 3 it's work perfectly, including the CSS. I have already changed the item class to carousel-item as it sends the documentation, but still I am not having success. I think the problem is very simple, but I can not find it. Could someone help me with this? I would appreciate it and apologize if you infiltrate some stackoverflow rule
My code is:

```css
.carousel-control {
  left: -12px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
  border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.carousel-control.right {
  right: -12px;
}


/* The indicators */

.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  right: 50%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -10px;
  margin-right: -19px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* The colour of the indicators */

.carousel-indicators li {
  background: #cecece;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  background: #428bca;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--.row-->
    </div>
    <!--.carousel-item-->

    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--.row-->
    </div>
    <!--.carousel-item-->

  </div>
  <!--.carousel-inner-->
  <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
  <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
</div>
<!--.Carousel-->
```

What can be this error?

Comment: Please explain what is the problem with arrows and cycles in brief.

Comment: The arrows and cycles dont work, dont show the icons

Answer (score 0):

The icons are not showed because you need to add a  inside the  tags and you can use predefined classes of bs carousel for controlling it:

```
<a id="previous" class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carrousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
</a>
<a id="after" class="carousel-control-next" href="#carrousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carouse`enter code here`l-control-next-icon"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for bootstrap 4 Carousel to work you have to add [jquery, popper and bootstrap js files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#js) to your project.

You can see in the link a section named *Show components requiring JavaScript*, in it your can see *Carousel for all slide behaviors, controls, and indicators*,

In the code you've added there is no sign for theme and this could be your problem.

You can see in this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-49952042) that your buttons are working. Take a look at index.html file where I've added this js file scripts (removing theme will reproduce your problem where the buttons are not working).